# Omniture: 'Unspecified' after changing tracked page name

Tags: adobe-analytics

We are using Omniture and encountered a weird problem.

Say, previously, we used 'Library' as the page name. On the my.omniture.com 'Pages Report' page, we can see the 'Page Views' number is correct.

Now If I change the name to be something else, like, 'Lib', the 'Page' column becomes 'Unspecified'. And then switch back, it counts to 'Library' correctly again! I can confirm that only the page name is changed.

Checked with [description from Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/analytics/kb/none-unspecified-and-unknown.html#id_91127), but cannot understand what is happening:

> Similar to "None," this result occurs when the breakdown is:
>
> 1. Correlation reports where only one variable fired: ...
> 2. Non-browser hits when viewing Technology reports: ...
> 3. Hierarchy reports with different amounts of levels: ...

And after googing, I could not find any helpful solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: contact Omniture support.